# How to make a right angled triangular cut on a div?

Tags: css, css-shapes

This is the result I want:

[image]

I am using borders like:

```
border: 10px blue solid;
border-right: 10px white solid;
```

but it just makes a trapezium like shape on the right side. Is there any way to achieve what I want in pure CSS? The `div` itself might contain some other DOM elements like `p`, `h1-h6` or some other `div`s.

Comment: Post your html and css which you have tried.

Comment: I have posted the CSS. I don't think rest of the CSS is relevant. It just sets background color and padding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's simple. Just use following css:

```css
.shape {
    border-top: 100px solid blue;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

**Edit:**

Following will work if there is another element inside it.

```css
.shape {
    background: blue;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
  color:white;
}
.shape::before {
    background: blue none repeat scroll 0 0;
    content: "";
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -25px;
    transform: skew(-20deg);
    width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape">
 <span>Hello</span> 
 <div> Test message </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks :). But It doesn't work if there is some other DOM element inside the div.

Comment: @SanJeetSingh check my edited answer.